# How to fix the SSRProvider Warning in React Native

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using NativeBase with my ReactNative App.
It is running ok.
However there is a warning that is bugging me a little bit.

How do I fix the warning below?

> When server rendering, you must wrap your application in an
>  to ensure consistent ids are generated between the
> client and server.
> FormControl@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=com.wenyang.DanceConnectyCube:162364:111
> RCTView View

Comment: Please track it here: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/4273

Answer (score 0):

First install this package
npm i @react-aria/ssr or yarn add @react-aria/ssr

Then import it into your App.js
import {SSRProvider} from '@react-aria/ssr';

Then do this

```
const App = () => {
 return (
  <SSRProvider> 
   <NativeBaseProvider> 
    <App /> 
   </NativeBaseProvider> 
  </SSRProvider>
     );
     };
```